# How to force 2 Python subprocesses to run one after the other

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run 2 programs in Python one after the other. I use Popen but it appears they run in parallel. I have something like this:

```
p1 = Popen(['./program1'])
p2 = Popen(['./program2'])
```

How can I make p2 to start only when p1 finish?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work.

```
p1 = Popen(['./program1'])
p1.wait()
p2 = Popen(['./program2'])
p2.wait()
```

it will cause the program to block until each subprocess exits.

Comment: you could write `Popen().wait()` as simply `call()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Popen.wait` method to wait until first process is finished